# Select entity through ManyToOne association in Doctrine2 DQL

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have two entities, UserAccount and UserEmail. UserAccount has a OneToMany association to UserEmail. What I want to do is select the UserAccount that has a given email.

How can I generate something like the following SQL JOIN query with DQL:

```
SELECT a.* FROM user_account a
    INNER JOIN user_email e ON e.account_id = a.id
    WHERE e.address = 'someone@example.com'
```

If I do `SELECT account, email FROM UserEmail email JOIN email.account account WHERE email.address = :email` it gives me back the email, which isn't really what I want.

Do I just have to get the email back and then get the account from that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what [fetch-joining](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins) is all about: your "email" object contains the account here.

```
SELECT e, a FROM UserEmail e JOIN e.account a WHERE e.address = :email
```

Then simply do

```
$account = $email->getAccount();
```

Another way of doing this is selecting all accounts with that email:

```
SELECT a FROM UserAccount a JOIN a.emails e WHERE e.address = :email
```

That will directly retrieve the account objects.